# When we are talking about

Tags: grammar, usage

- ***When** we are talking about these things*, we have to understand. ..
- ***If*** *we are talking about these things*, we ...

Is it possible to use a Present Continuous in this context after "When" and "If" ?

Is it grammatically correct

Comment: Yes, it's fine. In some contexts there's a genuine difference in ***meaning*** reflected by the choice between *If we **are talking** about it* and *If we **talk** about it*. The continuous version could refer to ***the possibility that we are in fact currently talking about it*** (perhaps our conversation has been guarded / circumspect, and until now we haven't been honest about what we're ***really*** talking about). But that distinction doesn't necessarily apply - in most contexts, ***when*** and ***if*** are more or less equivalent (except ***when*** implies more certainty that we do/will)

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Would you please stop peering into my mind while I write answers. It is very disconcerting.

Comment: @JeffMorrow: It's easier than thinking things up for myself! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica LOL

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is grammatically possible and indeed common.

The continuous identifies actions that occur throughout a **relevant** period of time. The first sentence is identifying a relevant period of time very explicitly with “when; it implies that there actually were, are, or very likely will be such times. The second is conditional; it does not imply that such times have actually occurred or even will occur.

As a matter of style, I prefer “while” to “when” in these examples because it further implies that what was just said is not necessarily true at times that are not relevant. But style is neither grammar nor idiom; it is opinion.

**EDIT**: Having seen Fumble’s initial comment to the OP’s question, I insert this preemptive edit. The slight differences in meaning that I have discussed are unlikely to be intended in everyday speech or careless writing. There, “when,” “if,” and “while” are often used interchangeably without any intention of implying different meanings.

Comment: (It's also easier to just upvote *your* answer rather than arrange my comment text into a properly-formatted answer and post it myself! :) Besides, I only had about 30 characters left in the comment, so it was a tight squeeze to get my intended meaning into ***except when implies more certainty that we do/will.*** Which ***should*** have been *...except "when" **could** imply...*

Comment: Yes, the length restriction does make writing some comments a challenge. And thanks for the upvote.

Comment: ***If we're engaging in mutual back-scratching***, perhaps we should cite this comment as an example of ONE of the contexts where ***if*** and ***when*** are NOT equivalent! :)

Comment: Indeed. "If" is entirely inappropriate here.

Answer (score 0):

Both "When we are talking about these things, we have to understand..." and "If we are talking about these things, we..." are grammatically correct.